# Can I declare a datasnap server method with array parameters?

Tags: json, delphi, datasnap

Parameters of Server methods in datasnap supports a number of data type.  `TArray<string>` or `array of string` shall be basic type, but the following `Test` method is not working:

```
type{$M+}
  TMyModule = class(TDSServerModule)
  public
    function ReverseString(Value: string): string;
    function Test: TArray<string>;
  end;
```

Is there an alternative way to get array works with server methods?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, there is.
All you need to do is to encapsulate your array in an object.
Here is an example for an array of integers :

`
    unit TransferObjects;

```
interface

type
  TIntArray = TArray<Integer>;

  TIntegerArray = class(TObject)
  private
    FValues: TIntArray;
    function GetValues: TIntArray;
    procedure SetValues(const Value: TIntArray);
  public
    property Values : TIntArray read GetValues write SetValues;
    constructor Create;
    function Length : Integer;
    procedure Resize(Count : Integer);
  end;

implementation

{ TIntegerArray }

constructor TIntegerArray.Create;
begin
  inherited create;
  Resize(0);
end;

function TIntegerArray.GetValues: TIntArray;
begin
  Result := FValues;
end;

function TIntegerArray.Length: Integer;
begin
  Result := System.Length(FValues);
end;

procedure TIntegerArray.Resize(Count : Integer);
begin
  SetLength(FValues, Count);
end;

procedure TIntegerArray.SetValues(const Value: TIntArray);
begin
  FValues := Value;
end;

end.

unit ServerMethodsUnit1;

interface

uses System.SysUtils, System.Classes, Datasnap.DSServer, Datasnap.DSAuth,
  TransferObjects;

type
{$METHODINFO ON}
  TServerMethods1 = class(TComponent)
  private
    { Private declarations }
  public
    { Public declarations }
    function ReverseArray(Value : TIntegerArray) : TIntegerArray;
  end;
{$METHODINFO OFF}

implementation


function TServerMethods1.ReverseArray(Value: TIntegerArray): TIntegerArray;
var
  i, l : Integer;
  Erg : TIntegerArray;
begin
  Erg := TIntegerArray.Create;
  Erg.Resize(Value.Length);
  for i := 0 to Value.Length-1 do
  begin
    l := Value.Length-1-i;
    Erg.Values[l] := Value.Values[i];
  end;
  Result := Erg;
end;
end.
```

`

This may not be very elegant, but it works (tested with XE6).
Like this the object can be (un)marshaled internally with JSON, the same code using interfaces instead does not work.

hth